# After broker restart, subscriber is not able to connect forever

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

Using ActiveMQ-5.10.

After restarting the broker, the client does not seem to be able to recover and forever spits out. Clients throws

[ 2014-12-18 18:17:58,852 [StatsCollector-3]  jmx.TCAQueueSizeMonitor.getPendingQueueSize():68 ERROR]: Exception while getting TCA queue size status!!!
 **javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed**

```
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:767)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createBrowser(ActiveMQSession.java:1425)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.createBrowser(PooledSession.java:294)
    at moss.jmx.TCAQueueSizeMonitor.getPendingQueueSize(TCAQueueSizeMonitor.java:63)
    at moss.jmx.TCAQueueSizeMonitor.getTCAQueueSizeStatus(TCAQueueSizeMonitor.java:101)
    at moss.jmx.TCAHeartBeatStatsCollector.run(TCAHeartBeatStatsCollector.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Session is closed once and then after it below exception continuously comes:

[ 2014-12-19 00:00:06,176 [securityEventDataSubscriberContainer-4105]  listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerSetupFailure():842 WARN ]: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'topic://check.newSecurityPublish' - trying to recover. Cause: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: Connection refused

[ 2014-12-19 00:00:06,476 [securityEventDataSubscriberContainer-4105]  listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful():891 INFO ]: Successfully refreshed JMS Connection

Please note that we are seeing this only for one client and that too sometimes. Other clients are able communicate with the broker properly.

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score -1):

Usually the client library won't implement the auto reconnect option with the brokers. I never worked with `ActiveMQ`, but I have good experience with `RabbitMQ` which is another server which does similar job as ActiveMQ. I written codes to handle the server disconnect on C#.

You have to do these things to make it happen, C# and Java have similar behavior, so you can easily implement it on java.

1. On the main while loop catch the Connection disconnect exception separately and handle it.
2. On the exception handling part is the place where you will try to reconnect with server and update the network socket and session objects,so you program can resume as usual.
3. Make sure you are retrying predefined number of times, after that you through error and your program exits. May be the server was actually dead.
4. You can reuse the connection reconnect part in the first time when you trying to connect with the broker.
5. You could make use of Async methods ( Non blocking function calls) for better implementation of this feature. In C# this can be done by using delegates and async calls.

Hope this will help you to handle the problem. I don't have much exposure to java, so I can't provide code samples to help you out.

Comment: ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ aren't the same thing, so experience with one isn't necessary relevant to the other.  ActiveMQ has a failover transport that will automatically retry a connection when it is lost, even if such a feature isn't available in RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Tim. Failover transport is interesting. I will check it out.